# Should I display related data in the same pop-up screen with save buttons?

Tags: buttons

I have a screen where the user have to enter two input 1. Valuation 2. Impact
Should I display the two in the same screen to make it easy for the user ?
It is correct to have two save buttons in the same screen ?

The user isn't expected to enter the both values (Valuation & Impact) at the same time –

[image]

Comment: What are your concerns and reasons for this question? Please add more context as it is now a matter of opinion.

Comment: Sure, The user isn't expected to enter the both values (Valuation  & Impact) at the same time

Comment: Why is that so? In the question title, you have mentioned that they are related data right? Would be good if you could mention why you went with the current version thats shown in the screenshot too – so we could help analyse and suggest further~ thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `save` operation in one screen will prevent a lot of confusion. If you wish to get two different sets of related data, consider using one of the following approaches:

1. Pagination — with the option to `save & continue` vs `save & exit`. Pagination allows you to make question mandatory within a page, even if the page itself is optional.
2. Stepper — with both sets of questions appearing sequentially, with a final `save` button. In this option, as in your design, all mandatory questions, related to both valuation and impact, will have to be filled out at one go.